# ¿Cómo imprimir errores de una app en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

En programas de **Java**, lo normal es utilizar `System.out.println();` para imprimir ciertos mensajes que ayuden a comprobar si el código tiene errores o si las variables no tienen los valores que uno espera. Pero en Android ¿cómo puedo hacer algo así?

Comment: si lo que buscas es ver en consola de alguna manera los errores o simples prints existe una clase llamada Log que te permite hacer eso te dejo la liga de la documentación. [Log.class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En su [documentación](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) Android propone varias maneras para ir depurando nuestro código:

## A. Usar el registro del sistema

El registro del sistema muestra mensajes del sistema mientras depuras tu app. Entre esos mensajes se incluye información sobre apps en ejecución en el dispositivo. Si deseas usar el registro del sistema para depurar tu app, asegúrate de que tu código escriba mensajes de registro e imprima el seguimiento de pila para las excepciones mientras tu app se encuentre en la etapa de desarrollo.

### Escribir mensajes de registro en tu código

Para escribir mensajes de registro en tu código, usa la clase [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html). Los mensajes de registro te ayudan a comprender el flujo de ejecución recopilando los resultados de la depuración del sistema mientras interactúas con tu app. Los mensajes de registro pueden indicarte la parte de tu aplicación que falló. Para obtener más información sobre el registro, consulta [Leer y escribir registros](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html).

En el siguiente ejemplo se muestra la manera en que podrías agregar mensajes de registro para determinar si hay información disponible sobre el estado anterior al iniciarse tu actividad:

```
import android.util.Log;
...
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() Restoring previous state");
            /* restore state */
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() No saved state available");
            /* initialize app */
        }
    }
}
```

Durante el desarrollo, tu código también puede detectar excepciones y escribir el seguimiento de pila en el registro del sistema:

```
void someOtherMethod() {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "someOtherMethod()", e);
    }
}
```

> Nota: Cuando estés listo para publicar tu app, quita los mensajes del
>   registro de depuración y las llamadas de impresión de seguimiento de
>   pila de tu código. También puedes hacer esto configurando un indicador
>   DEBUG y colocando mensajes del registro de depuración en las
>   declaraciones condicionales.

## B. Ver el registro del sistema (Android Studio)

En las ventanas Android DDMS (Dalvik Debug Monitor Server) y Android Monitor se muestran registros del sistema y procesos específicos de la app. Para ver el registro del sistema en la ventana de herramientas Android DDMS:

1. Inicia tu app como se describe en Ejecutar tu aplicación en el modo de depuración.
2. Haz clic en Android Monitor .

Si el registro del sistema está vacío en la vista Logcat, haz clic en Restart .

## C. Trabajar con puntos de interrupción

Android Studio admite varios tipos de puntos de interrupción que activan diferentes acciones de depuración. El tipo más común es un punto de interrupción de línea que pausa la ejecución de tu app en una línea de código específica. Mientras la app está pausada, puedes examinar variables, evaluar expresiones y luego continuar la ejecución línea por línea para determinar las causas de los errores en el tiempo de ejecución.

## D. Depurar marcos de una ventana

En la ventana Debugger, el subpanel Frames te permite inspeccionar el marco de la pila que condujo al alcance del punto de interrupción actual. Esto te permite navegar y examinar el marco de la pila e inspeccionar la lista de subprocesos en tu app de Android. Para seleccionar un subproceso, usa la flecha desplegable del selector de subprocesos y visualiza el marco de la pila. Cuando haces clic en los elementos del marco se abre el origen en el editor. También puedes personalizar la presentación de subprocesos y exportar el marco de la pila como se explica en la Guía de marcos de ventanas.

Hay otros, pero creo que esto responde a tu pregunta.

Para más detalles:  [Depurar tu app - Documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

En Android también se puede hacer uso de :

```
System.out.println();
```

o

```
System.out.print();
```

para imprimir valores o mensajes en la consola, pero en Android Studio tiene una herramienta especial para escribir y revisar registros o mensajes llamada **[LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html?hl=es)**, la cual se encuentra dentro del ADM y puedes acceder mediante:

`Tools` > `Android` > `Android Device Monitor`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu código puedes designar mensajes y administrarlos mediante el nivel de prioridad:

```
V — Verbose (prioridad más baja)
D — Debug
I — Info
W — Warning
E — Error
A — Assert
```

La estructura para mostrar mensaje dentro del LogCat es:

```
Log.d(etiqueta, mensaje);
```

por ejemplo si deseas imprimir un mensaje con prioridad Error (E):

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
...

try{
...
...
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```